# Delete a column from a css table

Tags: jquery, html, css

I think I got the delete row to work but the delete column button is not working correctly.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/blueberrymuffin/x7865gka/5/) to the code.
Thank you for the help.

HTML

```
<br/>
<button id="css-irow">Row +</button><br/>
<button id="css-drow">Row -</button><br/>
<button id="css-icol">Col +</button>
<button id="css-dcol">Col -</button>
```

jquery

```
$('#css-irow').click(function(){
        $(".ws-css-table-tr:last").clone(false).appendTo('.ws-css-table')
        .find(".ws-css-table-td").text("");
});

$('#css-drow').click(function(){
  $(".ws-css-table-tr:last-child").remove(); 
});


$('#css-icol').click(function(){
    $(".ws-css-table-tr").each(function(i, row){
        $(".ws-css-table-td:last", row).clone().appendTo(row).text("");
    });

$('#css-dcol').click(function(){
 $(".ws-css-table-td:last-child").remove(); 
});
```

CSS

```
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}
.ws-css-table-td { 
    display: table-cell;
    border:1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height:15px;
    text-align:center;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: I added an example below that fixes your scoping issue and the issue where your code does not handle a "table" with no rows or no cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because you have the closures messed up. The column delete is inside the column add so that click event is not attached until you add a column.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/x7865gka/6/

```
$('#css-icol').click(function () {
    $(".ws-css-table-tr").each(function (i, row) {
        $(".ws-css-table-td:last", row).clone().appendTo(row).text("");
    });
});

$('#css-dcol').click(function () {
    $(".ws-css-table-td:last-child").remove();
});
```

Comment: I have no idea what this means; but it works. Thanks. I will work on understanding it so I could do it myself in the future. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1763812 I'll explain. Just stepped out to grab lunch real quick.

Comment: Oh I messed up the });   .  Thanks for catching that.

Comment: @user1763812 Exactly. So because the attaching of the click event for deleting columns was inside the click event for adding it wasn't until you added a column that the event for deleting was attached,

Answer (score 1):

try this...  You code had a few issues including handling the case where the table is empty.

```js
function generateDefaultRow() {
    return $('<div class="ws-css-table-tr"><div class="ws-css-table-td"></div></div>');
}

$('#css-irow').click(function() {
    var row = $(".ws-css-table-tr:last");
    if(row.length === 0) {
        row = generateDefaultRow();
    }
    row.clone().appendTo('.ws-css-table')
        .find(".ws-css-table-td").text("");
});

$('#css-drow').click(function() {
    $(".ws-css-table-tr:last-child").remove(); 
});

$('#css-icol').click(function() {
    var rows = $(".ws-css-table-tr");
    if(rows.length === 0) {
        generateDefaultRow().appendTo('.ws-css-table')
        .find(".ws-css-table-td").text("");
    } else {
        rows.each(function(i, row) {
            $(".ws-css-table-td:last", row).clone().appendTo(row).text("");
        });
    }
});

$('#css-dcol').click(function() {
    $(".ws-css-table-td:last-child").remove(); 
    if($(".ws-css-table-td").length === 0) {
        $(".ws-css-table-tr").remove();
    }
});
```

```css
.ws-css-table {
    display: table;
}
.ws-css-table-tr { 
    display: table-row;     
}
.ws-css-table-td { 
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

<div class="ws-css-table">
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="ws-css-table-tr">
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
        <div class="ws-css-table-td"></div>
    </div>    
</div>

<div>
    <button id="css-irow">Row +</button><br/>
    <button id="css-drow">Row -</button><br/>
    <button id="css-icol">Col +</button>
    <button id="css-dcol">Col -</button>
</div>
```

Comment: wow. Thanks for this code and for catching the issues. It appears to work perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: For sure, I am a bit new at this, this means clicking the "Copy snippet to answer" button?

Comment: Sorry. Got it! I did that already. Thank you so much for your time. you make it look easy.